# non gaussian distributions with higher moments and time scaling properties?

Tags: distribution

If we assume a portfolio comprised of n asset classes, whose log returns can be modeled with a distribution. I am interested in finding a distribution that:

- incorporates higher moments (skewness and kurtosis)
- (ideally but not necessarily multivariate as I have n asset classes)
- that can be time scaled, i.e., the distribution of returns at time T
  can be expressed parametrically too (the same way assuming normal
  distribution and GBM, we have [image]

1. I came across the NIG distribution that has nice convolution property. Is there a way to scale it up in time? and if so how?
2. are there any other non gaussian distributions or approximations that you would recommend?

Many thanks

---

EDIT

Building on @Kermittfrog's answer, more details about how to scale up the NIG and the impact on the moments:

From the convolution property of the NIG it follows that the density at time T is given by:
[image]

And the moments evolve as follow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

i.e.  mean and variance increase with t and the skewness and kurtosis decrease over time with √t and t respectively.

Comment: If your returns are independent across time you simply scale the NIG distribution's location and scale parameter by $T$. The shape parameter should be unaffected. HTH?

Comment: Thanks @Kermittfrog for your suggestion If I understand correctly, the idea would be to scale the NIG as follows: NIG(α,β,δ*T,μ*T).One of the issue I am having with that is that increasing time greatly impacts the kurtosis for example. Any reason why we shouldn't multiple the other parameters by T too? I couldn't find answer in the literature (other than the convolution property)

Comment: If you aggregate (sufficiently) independent random variables, the skew and kurtosis of the aggregate will shrink. That’ll happen always, unless you add some intertemporal dependence, I think.

Comment: Did you look into mixing 2 normals as stated in your question? Might give the behavior you are looking for.